# Adding all inputs into an array

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

Intended Function: User should ender 1,2 or 3. 1 should allow the user to add a number to the array, 2 should allow the user to access the number at that point in the array, 3 should exit the program.

Problem: When the user is asked for a number and chooses 'yes' to add another, only the last number entered is added to the array. All numbers inputed should be added. Why is only the last one added?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneBookV2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] numbers = {};
        String[] moreNumbers = new String[numbers.length + 1];

        numbers = moreNumbers;

        print(numbers);
        task(numbers, moreNumbers);
    }

    public static void task(String[] numbers, String[] moreNumbers){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please Pick A Task: \n 1:Add A Number to Speed Dial \n 2:Speed Dial A Number \n 3:Exit");
        String choice = scan.nextLine();

        switch(choice){
            case "1":
                AddNumber(numbers , moreNumbers);
                break;
            case "2":
                CallNumber(numbers);
                break;
            case "3":
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static String[] AddNumber(String[] numbers,String[] moreNumbers) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean cont = false;

        do{
            System.out.print("Please Enter The Number You Wish To Save Under Speed Dial: ");
            moreNumbers[moreNumbers.length - 1] = scanner.nextLine();



            System.out.print("Would you like to add another? Yes or No: ");
            String answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if(answer.equals("yes")) continue;
            else if(answer.equals("no")) {
                print(numbers);
                cont = true;
            }

        }while(!cont);
        System.arraycopy(numbers, 0, moreNumbers, 0, numbers.length);
        return moreNumbers;
    }
    public static void printPhoneBook(String[][] keys){

        for(String[] row : keys){
            for(String s : row){
                System.out.print(s);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void print(String[] numbers){
        for(int i = 0; i< numbers.length; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1) + ") " + numbers[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Arrays in Java not allowed expand its size. Consider ArrayList instead of array.

Comment: If you must use an array instead of an ArrayList, then I recomend using the `Arrays.copyOf()` method to duplicate your array with an extra spot for the new number. Also I don't see why you need two arrays, consider using only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because an array in Java is fixed size. Let's look at your code:

```java
String[] numbers = {};
String[] moreNumbers = new String[numbers.length + 1];
```

You are creating a String array `numbers` of length 0 and another String array `moreNumbers` with the length of `numbers` added to 1 (e.g, length 1).

Then, you pass these arrays to the `task` method, where you add a number to the `moreNumbers` array.

```java
moreNumbers[moreNumbers.length - 1] = scanner.nextLine();
```

Here, you're setting a value (`scanner.nextLine()`) to the index 0 of `moreNumbers` (since `moreNumbers` has length 1). When you fetch another value, it's set to the same index 0 since `moreNumbers` did not change its size.

You can use the `add` method of `ArrayList`, which can resize:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

// ...

private static ArrayList<String> AddNumber() {
    // Create a new ArrayList to store the numbers
    final ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean cont = false;

    do {
        System.out.print("Please Enter The Number You Wish To Save Under Speed Dial: ");
        
        // Add the next number to the ArrayList
        numbers.add(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Would you like to add another? Yes or No: ");
        String answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if (answer.equals("yes")) continue;
        if (answer.equals("no")) {
            print(numbers);
            cont = true;
        }

    } while (!cont);
    return numbers;
}
```